# How can I make all GTK+ apps on Windows pick up themes from the same folder?

Tags: themes, gtk, gtk-windows

I have several GTK+ apps installed (pidgin, GIMP, KeepNote et al) and I also have GTK2 themes installed separately in one location. However, picking/selecting a theme from the GTK+ theme selector does not make all the apps use that theme unless I copy and paste all the themes (or at least the one I selected) manually to the "themes" folder for each app (even that doesn't work at times - for KeepNote, for instance). This gets rather tedious and is also a waste of space.

Isn't there a way to make all GTK+ apps use the same folder for themes? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

For that to work flawlessly the same (system wide) installation of GTK+ needs to be used by all applications. Right now the recommended procedure for Windows is to install all third party libraries privately for each application, effectively making each application an island (resulting in this kind of problems). This is because Windows provide no other solution for third party applications that's both reliable and reasonably user friendly. As perceive it there are two good solutions the the problem: either Windows provide a way for applications to specify which versions of third party libraries they need and they get automatically installed and updated (as in for example Linux) or Windows ships with it's own official build of GTK+ which third party applications has to be compatible with (as in for example Irix). That's the situation.

If you can accept a non user friendly solution on the other hand: I heard newer versions of Windows support symlinks so you can merge all the relevant files together in this way. But you might need to be attentive to different versions of GTK+. Or you can manually install and maintain GTK+ in it's own directory and delete it from all the applications directories. But doing that requires some understanding about Windows DLL handling.